# Cannot tag to GitHub because tag already exists

Tags: git, github

So I have a GitHub repository but I need to use SVN.  Fortunately, GitHub has a SVN Bridge.  I use TortoiseSVN with this as it's nice and easy and I love the colored icons in Explorer.

The problem is that GitHub is reporting that a tag already exists if the tag string forms part of an existing tag string.

For example.  If I tag 1.0.0.alpha on an empty repository, that works fine.  But if I then go on to tag 1.0.0, GitHub reports that 1.0.0 exists (which it obviously doesn't as the repository only contains the 1.0.0.alpha tag).

If the tag names are all completely unique (such as 1.0.1.alpha, 1.0.1.release), it works.  Is there a bug in GitHub's SVN Bridge?

Importing the repository works fine.  It's only when tagging that GitHub complains that a tag already exists when it doesn't.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you check the underlying git repository, does it have a tag named 1.6.1? Don't check the SVN version, go to the source.

Comment: On GitHub, I click on Releases.  I then browse through Releases and Tags.  1.6.1 is not there.  1.6.1.alpha.1 and 1.6.1.alpha.3 are both there but 1.6.1 is not there.
I then go back to the main repository page, click the Branch: master dropdown menu, click the Tags tab and enter 1.6.1.  Only 2 entries are listed - 1.6.1.alpha.1 and 1.6.1.alpha.3.  1.6.1 is not there.
As I said, 1.6.1 also does not exist in the tags folder in repository browser and its not there in the checked out repository either.  1.6.1 doesn't seem to exist anywhere but TortoiseSVN reports it does.

Comment: Then create the tag on GitHub or using a git client. Something appears off with the SVN interface. You could also contact GitHub for technical support.

Comment: I have contacted GitHub but it might take a while (last support ticket took over 3 days for a response).  I would rather keep using TortoiseSVN because it's simple and better suited to my workflow.  Besides the SVN Bridge should be fine.  I'm sure it's to do with my use of periods (.) in the tag name.

Comment: Git has no issues with dots/periods in the tag names. In fact it is standard in many projects to use tags that adhere to SemVer - which used dots. If anything it's with the (according to semver) incorrectly formatted version. The prerelease should probably be 1.6.1-alpha.3 and not 1.6.1.alpha.3. But it really shouldn't, though only GitHub will know the answer. You could however create a new repo just to test the theory.

Comment: I made a new repository.  I checked it out, created branches, tags and trunk folder and put a file in trunk folder.  I committed that as 1.0.0.  I then changed the file in trunk and committed that as 1.0.1_alpha.1.  I tagged it successfully.  I then changed the file again and committed it as 1.0.1.  That worked fine.  But then I tried to tag 1.0.1 and TortoiseSVN said /tags/1.0.1 already exists.  So replacing 1.0.1.alpha.1 with 1.0.1_alpha.1 didn't help.
Just for completeness, I then committed and tagged 1.0.2 and the tag worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm amazed!  I created a new repository, created branches, tags and trunk, put a file in trunk and committed as 100.  I made a file change and committed and tagged as 101alpha1.  I made another file change and committed as 101.  But when I tried to tag, it said /tags/101 already exists.  How is this possible?  No punctuation was used at all!

Comment: I'll assume that the SVN bridge is not fully implemented or has a bug that only checks the new tag  exists by doing a string.StartsWith instead of Equals (or equivalent functions for whichever language they are using). Work around it or switch to git :P

Comment: I think you might be right fredrik.  I commit and tag 103a and its fine.  I commit and tag 103b and its fine.  I then commit and tag 103 and it says 103 already exists.  No punctuation used at all.  It presumably let 103b through because 103b ~= 103a.  But 103 is part of 103b so it said tag already exists.  I had the same issue over a year ago so I would have expected if it was a bug, if would have been fixed by now.  Surely a company as huge as GitHub, owned by Microsoft, couldn't have an obvious and simple string comparison bug in their code?  Maybe they do.  I'll mention this to support.

Comment: I sent a followup ticket to GitHub support.  If/when they reply, I will update this here so that future SO readers can see that it is/was a bug and (hopefully) will be/was corrected.  I'm convinced that you're right, fredrik, it seems pretty conclusive.  GitHub doesn't check the tag string properly.  Instead of doing a simple string match, it seems to do a string contains which seems weird to me (less code to do a string match!)  Once GitHub respond (assuming they confirm it's a bug), I will update and close this as resolved.  If you write an answer (not a comment), I can mark it as correct.

Comment: While I wait for support to answer, I had a look at TortoiseGit.  So coming from an SVN user.
I clone the repo, I make changes, I commit and push.  When I want to release, I create a tag and push the tag.  Is my working copy still up to date after that?  I read somewhere that I should pull after a push.  But I am the only user for my repository so is there any need?

Comment: If you are the only user and no iperations are performed in the server (like merging pull requests) you should never need to pull. And if you do, do it before a push.

Comment: I didn't get any reply back from GitHub even though my support ticket issue was 100% reproducible, easy to reproduce and should be an easy fix (just replacing string find with string match).  It's odd because GitHub still advertise their SVN Bridge as a main feature but don't seem to want to support it.  Switching to Git is perfectly feasible and I can just use Clone, Commit, Push, Tag, Push Tag and have the same results but using SVN is like having a RAID1 mirror as I can checkout the entire tags folder in one go.  Is there a way to download every Git tag in one go?

Comment: When you have cloned a git repo - you have a complete clone of the repo on the server, all branches, all tags. If you need to checkout multiple tags at the same time you can use [`worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Comment: I'm not sure I explained it correctly.  If i run a git clone from my repository on GitHub, I only get the head (the trunk) files sent to my computer.  Running git worktree in that folder doesn't seem to do help as I only have the head on my computer.  If I run svn checkout <repo> and don't specify the trunk folder, it downloads branches, tags and trunk all together and I can look in any of the tags folders to see all my files from history.  I know Git doesn't work like this so I don't know if it's possible but how can I get all tags in folders from my entire repo history like svn checkout?

Comment: No, when you clone a repo you get everything - but only HEAD of default branch will be put in your workspace. It's the nature of git. If you want to test it, clone and then disconnect from internet and then swap branch

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now.  Thanks, that's most helpful.  That explains why the cloned folder size is 2mb but the files are only 512k.  I see that I can export any tag or commit but is there a way of getting every tag in its own folder, the way that I can do with svn checkout <repo>?  It looks like export only handles 1 tag at a time.  Any other way of getting them all in one go?  Since export is able to give me any tag, it seems like it should be possible to get all tags.

Comment: You would probably have to create a shell script, loop over all tags and use `git worktree` for each of them.

Comment: Just to update on the original problem which is that GitHub SVN Bridge doesn't check the tag name properly when tagging a release.  I was using TortoiseSVN in tests but I tried with command line SVN to see if it would be any different.  The result is that the command line copy (svn copy) seemed to work correctly (no errors) and when I checked out the repository after, the tag folders were created successfully.  But while 1.0.1.alpha.1 contained the correct files, 1.0.1 contained the trunk folder itself which I believe only happens if the tag already exists.  So this confirms it's broken.

Comment: I'll just add here that I have received no response whatsoever to my GitHub support ticket that I submitted nearly a week ago.  I'm hopeful that GitHub will respond since it's a genuine bug.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive help, @fredrik.  I cannot mark a comment for answer so I have submitted an answer using the information you provided (and of course crediting you for that information).

Comment: Just to let you know, @fredrik, you were quite right and GitHub have just emailed me to say that they identified an issue with the SVN Bridge which they have now fixed.  I subsequently tested a few tags and they all completed successfully even if the tag name strings formed part of existing tag name strings.  So it appears that GitHub Support have now fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fredrik pointed out, this was a bug in GitHub's SVN Bridge.  Using TortoiseSVN (GUI), tagging a release with a tag name string that formed part of an existing tag name string produced the 'tag already exists' error.  However, tagging a release with a completely unique tag name string worked fine.

Using Slik SVN (command line) produced different results.  Tagging a release with a tag name string that formed part of an existing tag name string prompted GitHub to add '/trunk' to the end of the release name.  However, tagging a release with a completely unique tag name prompted GitHub to name the tag correctly.

I was able to use these tests to demonstrate to GitHub Support that there was a bug in the GitHub SVN Bridge code and I'm happy to say that they have now fixed that bug.

It appears that I can now tag releases just fine on GitHub using TortoiseSVN with no errors even if the tag name string forms part of an existing tag name string.  So this issue appears to have been fixed by GitHub Support.